# How to make better jQuery search box with resize from right to left then mine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search-box

Im trying about same **search box** like here in top right side of page: [Search Box](http://powergame-themexpose.blogspot.in/)

I have this, but it doesn't work correctly:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#search").mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).stop().animate({marginLeft:'-40',width:"181"},300) 
  /*function(){
   $(this).animate({marginLeft:'0',width:"141"},300)
  });*/
 });
 $("#search").mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).animate({marginLeft:'0',width:"141"},300);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cs-cz">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <form id="searchbox" action="">
    <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Type here">
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a `float: right` or `text-align: right`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search").css({
    marginLeft: 0,
    width: 141
  });
  $("#search").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
      marginLeft: '-40',
      width: "181"
    }, 300);
  });
  $("#search").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      marginLeft: 0,
      width: "141"
    }, 300);
  });
});
```

```css
#searchbox {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="searchbox" action="">
  <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Type here">
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Comment: Great and something to it will comeback to normal faster? When i leave mouse. I think without lag on leave mouse

Comment: @HonzaSedloň You want it faster on mouseover and slower or delayed on mouseout, is it?

Comment: When i put mouse out, it take circa 1 second then it start to coming back. I want to remove that delay.

Comment: @HonzaSedloň Would you like to use pure CSS for this?

Comment: By the way, I am not getting any delays like you said @HonzaSedloň.

Comment: Oh god. I'm trying to solve this for 3 days and thanks of you i know, that problem is in Mozzila Firefox. In Microsoft Edge everything is fine :( Thank you! Solved

Comment: @HonzaSedloň Checked in Edge, IE 11, FF, Chrome. I guess it also depends on the speed of the system.